# How to expand a list of features based off one column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have the following example df:

```
year   school    occupation     a      b     c
2020   GA Tech     engineer     2     3      4
2020  GA Tech      Business     1     5      4
.
.
.
```

There are many of the same occupations. I want the following dataframe:

```
year   school       engineer_a     engineer_ b     engineer_c Business_a  Business_b Businesss_c
2020   GA Tech       2                3                 4         1         5             4
```

where it is transformed into one big row for that year. How would I do this?

I have tried pivot tables and I couldn't figure out a way to make it work.

Comment: As a side comment, there can be many of the same occupation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use [`.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot) in the following way:

```py
df = (df.pivot(index=["year", "school"], columns="occupation")
      .sort_index(level=1, axis=1))
df.columns = [f"{b}_{a}" for a, b in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
```

Result for the short sample:

```
   year   school  Business_a  Business_b  Business_c  engineer_a  engineer_b  engineer_c
0  2020  GA Tech           1           5           4           2           3           4
```

If your comment *"...  there can be many of the same occupation"* means that `df` could look like

```
   year   school occupation    a    b    c
0  2020  GA Tech   engineer    2    3    4
1  2020  GA Tech   engineer   20   30   40
2  2020  GA Tech   Business    1    5    4
3  2020  GA Tech   Business   10   50   40
4  2020  GA Tech   Business  100  500  400
```

then try

```py
df = (
    df.assign(count=df.groupby(["year", "school", "occupation"]).cumcount())
    .pivot(index=["count", "year", "school"], columns="occupation")
    .sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
)
df.columns = [f"{b}_{a}" for a, b in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index().drop(columns="count")
```

to get

```
   year   school  Business_a  Business_b  Business_c  engineer_a  engineer_b  engineer_c
0  2020  GA Tech         1.0         5.0         4.0         2.0         3.0         4.0
1  2020  GA Tech        10.0        50.0        40.0        20.0        30.0        40.0
2  2020  GA Tech       100.0       500.0       400.0         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform it into custom pivot with some logic like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [2020, 2020, 2021, 2021],
    'school': ['GA Tech', 'GA Tech', 'GA Tech','GA Tech'],
    'occupation': ['engineer', 'Business','Business', 'engineer'],
    'a': [2, 1, 2, 2],
    'b': [3, 5, 3, 3],
    'c': [4, 4, 0, 9]
})
print('input df:')
print(df.to_string(),'\n')
columns = ['year', 'school']
for i in range(len(df)):
    if all(df.at[i,'occupation'] not in column for column in columns):
        columns.append(f"{df.at[i,'occupation']}_a")
        columns.append(f"{df.at[i,'occupation']}_b")
        columns.append(f"{df.at[i,'occupation']}_c")
data = []
letterNumber = {
    "a": 3,
    "b": 4,
    "c": 5
}
for i in range(len(df)):
    data.append([])
    for j in columns:
        if '_' in j:
            occupation = j.split('_')[0]
            letter = j.split('_')[1]
            selectedData = df[
                (df['year'] == df.at[i, 'year']) &
                (df['school'] == df.at[i, 'school']) &
                (df['occupation'] == occupation)
            ]
            if occupation == df.at[i, 'occupation']:
                data[i].append(selectedData.values[0][letterNumber[letter]])
            else:
                data[i].append(None)
        else:
            data[i].append(df.at[i, j])
newDf = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = columns)
print('output df:')
print(newDf.to_string())
```

The console will be like this:

```
input df:
   year   school occupation  a  b  c
0  2020  GA Tech   engineer  2  3  4
1  2020  GA Tech   Business  1  5  4
2  2021  GA Tech   Business  2  3  0
3  2021  GA Tech   engineer  2  3  9 

output df:
   year   school  engineer_a  engineer_b  engineer_c  Business_a  Business_b  Business_c
0  2020  GA Tech         2.0         3.0         4.0         NaN         NaN         NaN
1  2020  GA Tech         NaN         NaN         NaN         1.0         5.0         4.0
2  2021  GA Tech         NaN         NaN         NaN         2.0         3.0         0.0
3  2021  GA Tech         2.0         3.0         9.0         NaN         NaN         NaN
```